surjective Ox-mod endomorphism on quasi-coherent finite type sheaf is bijective
Exercise 7.22 in Görtz-Wedhorn "Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes" goes as follows:
"Let $X$ be a scheme, $\mathcal{F}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite type. Show that any surjective $\mathcal{O}_X$-module endomorphism $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ is bijective."
I fail to see why the hypothesis of being quasi-coherent is necessary. Here is my proof:
Exactness of sheaf sequences is proven on stalks. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is of finite type, its stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$ is also of finite type at any point. By exactness of filtered inductive limits, we get a surjective endomorphism on $\mathcal{F}_x$ which, by the analogous result on finite type modules, is a bijection.
What exactly is wrong here?

You are right that quasi-coherence of $\mathscr{F}$ is unnecessary. As you have seen, it follows from the fact that every surjective endomorphism of a finitely generated module over a local ring is bijective.
